# can drywall be apply over plaster

Tags: walls, plaster

have fake stone on the out side of house and some how it seek through the wall and the plaster in side and got wet along wit the card board likr material. can you put drywall over plaster  what do you need to do?

Comment: Can you add some photos? It would help you get a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install drywall directly over plastered walls. **First** you need to solve the  water intrusion issue that damaged your plaster, or the drywall will end up being damaged the same way the plaster was.

Installing drywall over plaster is the same as installing it anywhere else except you may need longer fasteners (nails/screws). This forum is not the place to give comprehensive instruction on drywall installation but there are many sources for you to get that info...